# Eclipse Time Out

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, error-handling, timeout

I want to either delay the time the results take to load for my web application or reduce the time out session for test purposes. Is there a way to implement this? I am using eclipse and gae with Java.

// will the timeout session look something like this?

```
  setTimeout( function(){ window.location = "main.jsp"; }, 10000 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to do the same thing in Java?

If yes you have the method `Thread.sleep()`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Just be aware that the page execution time in GAE should be less than 30 seconds if you exceed it, it is will throw a `DeadlineExceededException`.